# How to supply a mean centered variable in a regression model

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression

I am trying to fit the following model:

[image]

using `lm` in R.

I cannot get my head around the following behaviour...

```
library(nlme)
library(plyr)
#create toy data set
df0<-Orthodont
df0<-ddply(df0, .(Subject), mutate, lag1=c(NA,distance[1:(length(distance)-1)]))
df0<-subset(df0, !is.na(lag1))
head(df0)
#   distance age Subject  Sex lag1
# 2     21.5  10     M16 Male 22.0
# 3     23.5  12     M16 Male 21.5
# 4     25.0  14     M16 Male 23.5
# 6     23.5  10     M05 Male 20.0
# 7     22.5  12     M05 Male 23.5
# 8     26.0  14     M05 Male 22.5

lm(distance ~ 1, data=df0)$coef
# (Intercept) 
#     24.6358 
lm(distance ~ lag1, data=df0)$coef
# (Intercept)        lag1 
#   6.2798336   0.7866844 
lm(distance ~ I(lag1-mean(distance)), data=df0)$coef
#              (Intercept) I(lag1 - mean(distance)) 
#               25.6604346                0.7866844
```

The intercept parameter in the first model is the overall mean of `distance`. Why does this not re-appear in the final model when I mean centre the lag variable?

Comment: I think this is a good question, but it would be a question better asked on Cross Validated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try centering by `mean(lag1)`?  Here is an example where it works as expected, but you do have to center on the same independent variable.

```
> set.seed(1)
> df <- data.frame(x=1:10, y=1:10+runif(10))
> lm(y ~ x, df)$coef
(Intercept)           x 
  0.5111385   1.0073410 
> lm(y ~ 1, df)$coef
(Intercept) 
   6.051514 
> lm(y ~ I(x - mean(x)), df)$coef
   (Intercept) I(x - mean(x)) 
      6.051514       1.007341
```

Comment: thanks. don't know why i could not see it earlier... as i understand it, my code does reflects the model i have up-top, where as yours solves my confusion in the R output?

Comment: @gjabel, my code was just trying to highlight that so long as you subtract the mean of the variable from the variable it will work.  Your only problem was you were subtracting the mean of the variable from the lagged variable instead of the mean of the lagged variable.